# Using Local Storage value in Cypress tests

Tags: cypress

I have an ID that is generated on each test I run. The ID is then stored in the Local Storage as I need to use this value as part of an URL later on.

Saving to Local Storage:

```
somethingModal.somethingElse().type(projectID);
localStorage.setItem('URL', projectID);
```

Which saves the ProjectID as expected in Local Storage.

When I try to use the ProjectID it returns a null value.

My code:

```
const visitURL = () => {
  it('should navigate to mosaic URL', () => {
    let URL = localStorage.getItem('URL');
    cy.log(URL);
    cy.visit(`https://${URL}.web.app`)
  })
}
```

Comment: At which time and place exactly do you store the value to the local storage?

Comment: Still null @agoff

Comment: Cannot save a dynamic variable to Cypress.env @Fody

Comment: In the same test @Sebastiano Vierk

Comment: But saving to localStorage is not part of the test you posted in the question after "My code:". So again, where exactly do you execute the setItem method?

Comment: In case you set the item in another test or in a beforeEach operation, then @Fody is correct with his answer that Cypress clears the localStorage before each single test.

Comment: I have one test where I save to local storage:

somethingModal.somethingElse().type(projectID);
localStorage.setItem('URL', projectID);


Then I have another test where I call it:
let URL = localStorage.getItem('URL');
cy.log(URL);
cy.visit(`https://${URL}.web.app`);


It works in the same test, but not when used in a different test (Still in the same describe though). 
Which makes me think that @Fody is correct in saying that Cypress clears the localStorage

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the variable isn't set when Cypress uses the variable. [Filip Hric's blog does a good job of explaining this.](https://filiphric.com/cypress-basics-variables)

Luckily, in this case, we can probably just use the value directly in the `cy.visit()` command.

```js
it('should navigate to mosaic URL', () => {
  cy.visit(`https://${localStorage.getItem('URL')}.web.app`);
  // rest of test
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Cypress clears localStorage between tests, so it's not a good place to stash values.

Try setting it as an environment variable

```js
Cypress.env('URL', projectID)
```

```js
const visitURL = () => {
  it('should navigate to mosaic URL', () => {
    let URL = Cypress.env('URL');
    cy.log(URL);
    cy.visit(`https://${URL}.web.app`)
  })
}
```